# What exactly does it mean that a charged body has potential $V$?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage

Does it mean it takes $V$ joules of energy to move a unit positive charge from infinity to that body?

Answer (score 0):

Well, imagine you're sitting on a body that holds a positive charge, and you're holding a string connected to another positively charged body. The force between the bodies is repulsive, so to bring them together you need to pull on the string. That takes work. That's your energy.

Of course, the bodies can't really be infinitely far apart, but if they are far enough apart the work to bring them closer is negligible. It's convenient to take infinite distance as the initial condition simply because otherwise your calculation needs to carry around an additional parameter, the maximum distance.

Answer (score 0):

If the potential of the body is $+x\: V$ (Volt), then it takes $x\: eV$ (electronvolt) of energy to move a positive unit charge (charge of one proton) from infinity to that body ($1\: eV = 1.602\cdot 10^{-19} Joules$)

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential of a charged body depends on point where the electric potential is assigned a value of zero. Then the electric potential at the location of the charged body equals the work required per unit charge (Joules per Coulomb) to move a test charge from the zero reference point to the location of the charged body. Once the reference point is selected the potentials at all other points are fixed with respect to the reference point.

The selection of the zero potential reference point is technically arbitrary. But for a charged body consisting of a point charge the logical selection of the zero reference point is an infinite distance away from the charged body where the strength of the electric field approaches zero. Infinity would not be a logical choice for zero potential if the charged body consists, for example, of an infinite plane of charge where the electric field does not decrease away from the plane.

Because of the arbitrary nature of the reference point one is typically, but not necessarily, more interested in the potential difference (voltage) between points rather than the absolute value of the potential at a given point. An example where assigning potentials is useful is circuit node analysis applying Kirchhoff’s current law to determine node voltages. Zero potential is typically assigned to the negative terminal of a battery or to a node that’s common to multiple branches.

Hope this helps.